# What does putValue(MNEMONIC_KEY, KeyEvent.VK_S) do?

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, event-handling

I had a problem which is fixed by the answer to the following question:
[Java Thread Start-Stop-Start on same button click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41349229/java-thread-start-stop-start-on-same-button-click)
I know what it does, but I do not know exactly why. The things I do not fully understand are the blocks that look like this:

```
private class StartAction extends AbstractAction {
public StartAction() {
       super("Start");
            putValue(MNEMONIC_KEY, KeyEvent.VK_S);
        }
```

I have been searching a long time but cannot find the answer to what the putValue exactly does and what the input arguments are/do. If im correct, we look for the method StartAction("Start") in the Superclass AbstractAction. But, what does putValue do and how does StartAction know what to do with the input "Start"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> what the putValue exactly does

It just sets a property of the `Action`.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Actions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html) for more information and a list of all the properties.

When you add an `Action` to a Swing component (JButton, JMenuItem etc), The the properties of the `Action` are used to configure the component. So the same "text" can be used on all components, the "enabled" state will be the same for all components etc.

In the case of the mnemonic property a `Key Binding` will be set up automatically so that you can invoke the `Action` when the `KeyStroke` is used. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Key Bindings](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html)